# por que o column-count nao funciona no firefox?

Tags: html, css, css3

por que o atributo `css` `column-count` nao funciona no mozilla firefox segue abaixo como esta ficando no `google chrome` e no `mozilla firefox`

`Mozilla firefox`
[image: mozilla firefox]

`Google chrome`
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como faço para que no `mozilla firefox` fique igual ao `google chrome`?

codigo:

`CSS`

```
.imagem{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 4px;
    min-width: 0rem;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: none;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}
.img{
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    -moz-break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
#container{
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    -webkit-column-count: 6;
    -moz-column-count: 6;
    column-count: 6;
}
```

`HTML`

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="container">
    <div class="img">
      <div class="imagem">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="caminho das img">                                                          
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

como eu faço para que no `firefox` fique igual ao `chrome`?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que existe algo que está quebrando sem ser o column-count o mesmo é suportado a partir do mozilla 2.0 se puder adicionar mais detalhes ou um maior trecho de código. Obrigado!

Qualquer duvida sobre : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp)

Comment: opa adicionei o resto do `html` e o respectivo trecho do `css`

Comment: Acho que encontrei o problema. retire o padding: padding-right: 2px;  padding-left: 2px; do .img e veja se funciona.

Comment: nao continua o mesmo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yvnbsLfo/ adicionei para cada img o col-md-12 do Bootstrap, veja se funciona.

Comment: nao funciono eu estava lendo um artigo em que um usuario mandou tirar o `float:left` e adicionar o `inline-block` na minha classe `.img` porem quando eu altero no codigo ele nao funciona mas quando eu altero no modo desenvolvedor do mozilla ele funciona voce sabe me dizer o porque isso ocorre?